# Ubuntu, Windows dual boot: Windows will not start

Tags: dual-boot

I started with Windows 7 on a Toshiba laptop, and wanted to add Ubuntu 11.04 in a dual boot configuration. I installed Ubuntu using the standard install, and it seems GRUB has detected both Windows and Ubuntu.

Ubuntu works fine, but when I try to boot Windows it will not load. It gets to the "starting Windows" animation, which plays for about two seconds, and then reboots the computer. It seems that none of the safe mode, etc., options do anything to help this problem.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to even begin addressing this problem, since I can't even get into a command prompt in Windows. It seems that the partitions are fine (see below), but maybe there is something here I don't know.

If anyone has an idea on what I should try next, I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
***@sctoshlinux:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for ***: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb7784a6c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         192     1536000   27  Unknown
/dev/sda2             192       23548   187606782    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3           37753       38914     9324544   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           23548       37753   114102273    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           23548       37264   110171136   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           37264       37753     3930112   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the windows-install-cd or dvd , most of the time is it so.  While you can start ubuntu.  Go to the internet and download Hirens Boot cd. With some google you will find it easely.  Download the iso file, burn it to a Cd, and boot from the cd  and now follow the menu. You will see the possibility to start you windows configuration, and eventually go back to a restore point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start your Windows-Install-CD or -DVD. There you'll find an option to repair your installation. Windows creates a new boot file and afterwards your Windows should start again.

Usually there are problems when someone uses hard drive encryption which comes with Windows. But from what I heard this happens mostly in Vista.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can find torrent's of the recovery portion of the windows 7 cd. Legal grey area, but perfectly moral imho.